# What is the difference between the two?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

Given a uniformly charged hemispherical shell of radius $R$, I want to calculate the potential at the center of the shell.
I can use the equation $V=k\int\frac{\sigma}{r}da$, where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density, $r$ is the distance between the center and the surface element $da$
But can i calculate $\vec E$ at the centre of the sphere and then use $V=-\int \vec E.\vec {dl}$? Also, where should i place my reference point if the potential does not goes to $0$ at infinity?

Comment: You can’t calculate $\int \vec E\cdot d\vec {l}$ if you know $\vec E$ at only one point along the path of the line integral. To use this formula you would have to know it everywhere along the path.

Answer (score 0):

$V=k\int\frac{\sigma}{r}da$ gives automatically the potential  difference between infinity and the centre.(as potential is assumed 0 to be at infinity )

> Also, where should i place my reference point if the potential does not goes to 0 at infinity?

$V=-\int \vec E.\vec {dl}$ gives the potential difference not the potential .

Potential is assumed 0 to be at infinity therefore you get potential at that point. If you assumed potential value to be say X at infinity then $V_{centre}-V_{infity}=V_{centre}-X$.
In a short you can choose your reference point anywhere in the space but then you have to be careful using the standard formulae .

Comment: but the electric field $\vec E$ at the center is $\frac{-\sigma}{4\epsilon_0}\hat{z}$, so it is not zero at infinity, so if i use the first formula, i would be wrong isnt it?

Comment: @1500kook12 Are you saying that at infinity Electric field is not 0 but why potential is  ?

Comment: i mean the first equation as you told assumes that potential is $0$ at infinty but in this case it is not $0$ at infinity so is it not wrong to use the  formula $V=\int \frac{\sigma}{r}da$?

Comment: @1500kook12 No , Just use $V_{centre}-V_{infinty}$ in this case too.

Comment: So $V_{infinity} is 0 ?$ yes i just realised i am asking why electric field is not zero but potential is?and how do we know that potential is zero?

Comment: @1500kook12 Potential is a relative term. You can assume potential to be 0 anywhere. We take potential infinity  to be 0 , just a convention.As i told you u can assume potential to 0 anywhere but will have to make adjustments accordingly.